# How to use Slave Select on SPI Transceiver

Tags: avr, spi, wireless

I'm an absolute idiot when it comes to wireless technologies, but I'm kinda familiar with protocols over cables. Because of that, I know about the SS on SPI busses and that there is a separate cable for every signle device.
When it comes to Wireless, is there a address inserted at the beginning like in I2C or how is it implemented?

I might be totally asking the wrong question here, but I need a starting point to continue my own research.

Notes:

I'll be using an avr Arduino, so any software implementation to use the SPI interface in a I2C fashion is also suitable.

Also, this is for a project of Home Automation, so there will be many devices, but I will try to keep the communication to a minimum and in bursts.

[This is the transceiver I'm looking at right now](http://www.ebay.com/itm/2PCS-E07-M1101D-SMA-Ebyte-530m-CC1101-SPI-433MHz-Wireless-Transceiver-Module-/191974913426)

Comment: What does the datasheet say?

Comment: @Ignacio I have no idea, I haven't even seen the spreadsheet yet - that is, I haven't been able to find it.

Comment: That tranceiver you're looking at is SPI interface. It looks like you will need to implement your own air interface stack. You might want to see whether something lightweight like 6LoWPAN is compatible with the transceiver (almost certainly should be).

Comment: You use SPI to send the data to the module.  The module does NOT function as a SPI over RF extender.  It just transmits the data you give it over the air.

Comment: There is an Arduino SPI library, and it is pretty straight forward to use.  You must set the SS line yourself, though.  It really just amounts to setting a GPIO low before sending data, then setting it high again when finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format of data transmitted over SPI is completely device dependent. Typically there is no address byte as per I2C as this functionality is provided through the slave select pin (i.e. selecting the slave to talk to through hardware vs software).

Part of the draw of SPI is that it is an inherently synchronous protocol meaning that you can operate over a very wide range of frequencies (from virtually DC operating with buttons, all the way up to tens of Megahertz).

The key parameters to pay attention to when getting started with SPI and checking device compatibility.

**Clock Phase**  - Transfer data on the rising or falling edge of the clock

**Clock Polarity** - What  is the state of the clock when inactive (read not selected)

**Enable Polarity** - Does slave select high or low enable the slave.

**Maximum Clock Frequency** - The maximum clock frequency the slave can tolerate.

---

Edit: I somehow missed the part about wireless

Wireless devices can operate with many different protocols and is a very wide field (just like sending signals over cables is). The best way to get started with wireless for a home automation project is to use a module that will take care of the wireless protocol for you, you then command this module through an interface like SPI or I2C.

The particular transceiver you listed is more bare bones and you will have to come up with and implement your own protocol. I believe Jeff over at [JeeLabs](http://jeelabs.org/) uses modules similar to these and has done extensive work using them for home automation purposes.

Alternately Ebay can be a good source of cheap modules that also manage the firmware. I have had good experience with the below in home automation related projects.

- **HC-05 Modules**, these are a Bluetooth device that can be used as a transparent link (feed ttl level async serial into the module, and get characters out on a Bluetooth console on your master device (phone, laptop etc))
- **ESP8266 Modules**, these come in many flavors and variety and can even be programmed directly using the Arduino development environment. These can connect to regular wifi access points or even broadcast a network. High level librarys are also available allowing use as a micro webserver or to connect to use internet of things protocols such as MQTT.

Comment: Doesn't Arduino have a library for SPI functions? Or is that for communication with a (in between) module you mentioned?

Comment: Arduino does have a library that covers SPI but it will still need to be configured with the parameters I mentioned in the first half of my comment. SPI is a protocol that specifies how the bits go through the wires but nothing about what that data means or represents. I.e. it is not uncommon to have SPI packets that are weird numbers of bytes long say 22 for example. You will need to read up on the datasheet for your module to figure out what it needs to be sent to first set the module up and then to send the data.

Answer (score 1):

Please note: The connection between Arduino and this device is SPI, but it doesn't implement "wireless SPI".
It's up to you to implement any communication protocol.

Comment: Is it? Oh. But I still have to follow the basic idea of the SPI protocol, like using the clock signal (SCLK), etc., or?

Comment: @Areuz: Of course, the communication to this transceiver itself must be SPI, but, for instance, the "Slave Select" is used only to select different transceivers **on the same board**, not over the air.